# Replace 2 mirrored (RAID 1) drives with two news drives and keep the data?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, replacement

I have a Qnap TS-419P+ and running 4 drives in two groups mirrored. 2 x Hitachi HUA723020ALA641 MK7O and 2 x Hitachi HDS723020BLA642 MN6O.

I want to replace one of both sets now with 2 new Toshiba MG06ACA600E drives and my plan to do this is this:

- Remove one of the old 2tb drives
- Add a new 6tb
- Wait for the mirroring / rebuild to be done
- Remove the second old 2tb drive
- Add the second new 6tb drive

I've never done this before and I'm not sure if I can simply remove the drive from the bay, the system supports hot swap, but I don't think this is the best way? Also is this going to end up with a new 6tb volume or will it format the drives to just 2tb because the old one was just 2tb?

Or let me ask directly: Whats the best strategy to keep the data and replace the 2 mirrored disks with the new disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> end up with a new 6tb volume or will it format the drives to just 2tb because the old one was just 2tb

mdadm partitions use the same size partitions. Larger target will only use the original partition size.

> best strategy to keep the data and replace the 2 mirrored disks with the new disks

I would:

1. Create a new array with the new drives
2. Copy data from old array to new array. You will need to boot into a recovery image to do this safely
3. Configure the OS to use the new array
4. Remove the old array and wipe old drives

This does not destroy any data until the final step. You might have to do steps 2-4 twice (one for each mirrored old drive) depending on how many discs your system can handle at once.

Comment: Also has the advantage of removing the possibility of problems with going from 512byte to 4096 byte block sizes.